# What is the counter for kingdoms?

Tags: counters

I'm trying to write that a person is a citizen of two kingdoms, one earthly, one spiritual. What is the counter for kingdom? (王国). Also, what is the best website to find a list of counters? I've found some short lists, but I'm looking for a comprehensive list.

Comment: Bear in mind that short list means list of well-known ones. The more exhaustive the list the more arcane or archaic the counters may become.

Answer (score 7):

Most naturally (and most commonly as well), "two kingdoms" would be 「[ふたつの王国{おうこく}](https://search.yahoo.co.jp/search?p=%E2%80%9D%E3%81%B5%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A4%E3%81%AE%E7%8E%8B%E5%9B%BD%E2%80%9D&aq=-1&oq=&ai=QPWVqZKpRJqYDQmeiYt90A&ts=18497&ei=UTF-8&fr=top_ga1_sa&x=wrt)」.

After the actual names of the two kingdoms have been mentioned, however, you can safely use 「両王国{りょうおうこく}」.  It would be highly unnatural and awkward to keep repeating 「ふたつの王国」.

(You cannot use 「両 + Noun」 before both have been identified.  You can use 「ふたつの王国」 anytime.)

Answer (score 4):

I would use 箇国, the counter for countries.

箇 can be written in many ways, usually as ヶ (ヶ国).

---

**Resources for Japanese Counters**

- [Tofugu. 350 Japanese Counters Grouped by Usefulness](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/japanese-counters-list/)
- [Wikipedia. Japanese counter word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_counter_word#Common_counters_by_category)